# Cannot change root access in MySQL to %

Tags: mysql

This is a new MySQL Server install. I created my root password as part of the setup (on Centos 6.4).

When I connect to the server through a terminal, I can connect to MySQL and issue commands, using my root password.

select current_user;

gives me:

```
+----------------+
| current_user   |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

If I do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I get:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But when I do:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

Here's what I get:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*fdfgdgdggfggfgfg' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Am I not supposed to see another line for root@% in addition to root@localhost?

The real issue I'm having is that I can't connect to MySQL from outside of localhost (as in, I'm logged in using a terminal session), and if the MySQL server is not giving root universal access (root@%), then that would explain the problem.  When I try to connect using PHP (from my local MAC), the following is the returned MySQLi object:

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 
    [client_info] => 
    [client_version] => 50008
    [connect_errno] => 2002
    [connect_error] => Connection refused
    [errno] => 
    [error] => 
    [field_count] => 
    [host_info] => 
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 
    [server_info] => 
    [server_version] => 
    [stat] => 
    [sqlstate] => 
    [protocol_version] => 
    [thread_id] => 
    [warning_count] => 
)
```

Comment: perfect question to get answered at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you sure you want to have root access from any machine out there?  Have you thought about the security implications?

Comment: At this point, I'm opening it up to figure out why things are not working, when it starts working, I will restrict it to a set of IP addresses